# Insert Into using Max()

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I have a training database I've put together and all the data is loaded into a training history table. Much of the training is repeated on a regular basis and I use queries to refresh subject tables to hold only the most recent training information for that subject.  I want to replace these Access queries with SQL but can't get the syntax correct (self taught).  Below is the SQL view from one of the queries that pulls the employee ID, employee name, and most recent forklift training date for each employee and puts it into the forklift table. (It's actually more complicated than that or I would simply update the training date, but I stripped down the query so it wouldn't get too confusing.)

So I just need to know how this code would need to be modified so that it will work as an SQL command.

```
INSERT INTO Forklift_tbl ( EmpID, FullName, ForkliftTrainDate )
SELECT TrainHist_tbl.[EmpID]
     , TrainHist_tbl.[FullName]
     , Max(TrainHist_tbl.[TrainDate]) AS MaxOfTrainDate
FROM TrainHist_tbl
GROUP BY TrainHist_tbl.[EmpID]
       , TrainHist_tbl.[FullName]
       , TrainHist_tbl.[CourseName]
HAVING (((TrainHist_tbl.[CourseName])= 'Forklift Operator Training'));
```

Data table TrainHist:

```
EmpID| FullName  | CourseName| TrainDate
  123| Doe, John |   Forklift| 1/1/16
  123| Doe, John |        AED| 2/2/16
  123| Doe, John |   Forklift| 2/6/17
  234| Smith, Bob|   Forklift| 1/2/16
  234| Smith, Bob|        AED| 2/2/16
  234| Smith, Bob|   Forklift| 3/7/17
```

Result inserted into forklift table

```
  123|  Doe, John|   Forklift| 2/6/17
  234| Smith, Bob|   Forklift| 3/7/17
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: It does not seem helpful to Group By TrainHist_tbl.[CourseName], as you are filtering on only one value.

Comment: I'm using Access 2016. The code I put in was the sql view of an Access Query which of course doesn't translate well to VBA/SQL, I just put it in to illustrate what I was after.  Guess that just made it more confusing.

Comment: Just want to pick up the most recent info from a table, then refresh another table.  The information in the table is a lot more complex than shown, but if I know how to code this, it would get me started. 

TrainHist
EmpID|    FullName| CourseName| TrainDate
123|  Doe, John| Forklift|  1/1/16
123|  Doe, John| AED|         2/2/16
123|  Doe, John| Forklift|  2/6/17
234|  Smith, Bob| Forklift|  1/2/16
234|  Smith, Bob| AED|         2/2/16
234|  Smith, Bob| Forklift|  3/7/17
…………
Result inserted into forklift table
123|  Doe, John| Forklift|  2/6/17
234|  Smith, Bob| Forklift|  3/7/17

Comment: It's best to add data to the question itself where you can format it nicer, in columns.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean by "replace these Access queries with SQL".  Access queries are essentially SQL that is generated by the Query designer.  Do you mean that you want to create VBA procedures/functions to do the same?  If so, the SQL itself can be identical and doesn't necessarily need to be "modified".  It of course needs to be passed to an VBA method as a string, etc., but please show what you have done so far in regards to VBA code.

Comment: Saving calculated data is usually not advised, especially aggregate data. Calculate when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this reduced query:

```
INSERT INTO Forklift_tbl ( EmpID, FullName, ForkliftTrainDate )
SELECT TrainHist_tbl.[EmpID]
     , TrainHist_tbl.[FullName]
     , Max(TrainHist_tbl.[TrainDate]) AS MaxOfTrainDate
FROM TrainHist_tbl
WHERE TrainHist_tbl.[CourseName] = 'Forklift Operator Training'
GROUP BY TrainHist_tbl.[EmpID]
       , TrainHist_tbl.[FullName];
```

Comment: Yes! Now I think I can take it from here.Thanks!